# How to use Custom Font in Searchable Dictionary?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I build my own dictionary app. But I try to use custom font in My app. Then it can not show the definiation of the words. Please help me where Am I false. I don't know how to use custom font. Where Am I false?

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/*
** Copyright 2010, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<!-- Layout for SearchableActivity.
 -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="@string/search_instructions"
        android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/abc_search_url_text_pressed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dictionary;

import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

/**
 * The main activity for the dictionary.
 * Displays search results triggered by the search dialog and handles
 * actions from search suggestions.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Because this activity has set launchMode="singleTop", the system calls this method
    // to deliver the intent if this activity is currently the foreground activity when
    // invoked again (when the user executes a search from this activity, we don't create
    // a new instance of this activity, so the system delivers the search intent here)
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

/**
 * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
 * @param query The search query
 */
private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

        // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition };

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
public class CustomFontAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public CustomFontAdapter(final Context context, final int layout, final Cursor c, final String[] from,
                final int[] to, final int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        final TextView TextViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/PangLong.ttf");
        TextViewTitle.setTypeface(customFont);                           
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't called `CustomFontAdapter` but `SimpleCursorAdapter`!

Comment: Check this question: [Using custom simpleCursorAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708971/using-custom-simplecursoradapter)

Answer (score -1):

this is how you set custom font if you have a .ttf file in your assets folder.

```
    //Set font style
    Typeface tf;
    // Font path
    //public static  String fontPath = "fonts/TELE2.TTF";
    public static  String fontPath = "fonts/SketchRockwell-Bold.ttf";
    TextView tv_title;
```

// in onCreate():

```
    tv_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_tv_title);
        //Set font style
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
        tv_title.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Hope you have checked his question fully! He has already used the same code in `CustomFontAdapter` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but still have the same before.

Comment: Check the link given by @PareshMayani.

Comment: Please help, i can't use the custom font on my app until now.