# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter for Populating Rows of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to define a Custom SimpleCursorAdapter Class, which will be used to populate the rows of a ListView. I am using the v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter library for backward compatibility. I am having issues with the following two parts of the code.

In the constructor, I am using

```
super(context,layout,c,from,to);
```

Meanwhile, this is deprecated, and I am not sure how to modify it.

Also, in

```
alarm_activated = (ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.alarm_activated);
```

"row" cannot be resolved, and I am not sure how to reference the rows in question. (This syntax was working in a ArrayAdapter, and I was hoping that it would also work in a SimpleCursorAdapter...).

Perhaps, some other parts of my code (found hereafter) are incorrect.

```
    class AlarmRowAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AlarmRowAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context,layout,c,from,to);
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        alarm_activated = (ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.alarm_activated);

        if (activationInt == 1) {
            alarm_activated.setChecked(true);
            alarm_activated.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        } else {
            alarm_activated.setChecked(false);
        }

        alarm_activated.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                } else {
                    buttonView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.LTGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: In `bindView()`, use `view` instead of `row`. Then use the constructor that's not deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int).

Comment: Thank you Mike. I have used view instead of row, as suggested, and this has solved the problem. Meanwhile, regarding the constructor, I am using the one not deprecated already (as seen in the code). Nonetheless, it appears that I have to add the "super(context,layout,c,from,to);" piece in the constructor (which displays the "super" keyword as underlined in Android Studio, stating that it is deprecated). If I remove that piece, I obtain an error stating that there is no default constructor available in the support library used. J

Comment: "I am using the one not deprecated already (as seen in the code)." – I don't see that anywhere. You're missing the `flags` argument.

Comment: You need the `flags` argument in the `super` call. You don't really need it in your constructor declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Following suggestions made by Mike M. (please refer to comments above), here is the working code in case someone else would find it useful. Also, please note that I had used the example found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708971/using-custom-simplecursoradapter) when developing my initial code (thank you to Bobbake4 for that code).

```
    class AlarmRowAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;


    public AlarmRowAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context,layout,c,from,to, flags);
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        alarm_activated = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_activated);

        if (activationInt == 1) {
            alarm_activated.setChecked(true);
            alarm_activated.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        } else {
            alarm_activated.setChecked(false);
        }

        alarm_activated.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                } else {
                    buttonView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.LTGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For standard constructor add a flag parameter: [CursorAdapter doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int))

```
super (context,layout,c, from,to, 0);
```

And you are trying to use `row.findViewById` But the variable row doesn't exist. Since the parameter is `view`, you should use `view.findViewById`